# Using the Keyboard to show a context menu in a data bound WPF TreeView

Tags: wpf, treeview, contextmenu

I've got a DataBound (via HierachicTemplates) WPF TreeView that works fine with the mouse, but I want it to able to drive it with the keyboard. I've added CommandBindings so that ContextMenu items can be executed via 'gestures'; like CTRL+Delete to remove the currently selected item, but what I want is for the 'Properties' key to display the context menu and for the user to be able to use the cursor keys to navigate it.

I created a CommandBinding and debugged it but the RoutedUIEvent does have a ContextMenu. I tried creating it from the Xmal Resources and that worked but it is clearly not correct as everything is disabled.

How do I create a WPF ContextMenu that I can navigate with the keyboard?

Answer (score 2):

I managed to display an control's ContextMenu like this :

- listen for your KeyboardEvent (property key down for instance)
- in the handler, get your control (by name or whatever method)
- when you have your control, simply do : `myControl.ContextMenu.IsOpen = true;`

hope it helps.

Comment: Tried that but this is a TreeView the event is fired on a TextBlock element which is the node in the tree and that doesn't have a ContextMenu. This seems to be bound to something higher up (the visual tree?). The contextMenu is a TreeView resource. I also tried placing the context menu on the TextBlock but that didn't seem to help.

Comment: the problem here lies in my opinion in the control on which to set the contextMenu. If your event is fired on a textBlock, I'd suggest trying to find the nearest parent of this textblock in the treeview that has the "ContextMenu" Property, set your contextMenu to this control and then when the event is fired, go up the visualTree from your TextBlock so as to get this parent control and do the "ContextMenu.IsOpen = true" like I suggested. I do not see any easier way to do this.